# Error When Kivy Buildozer Disassembled APK

Tags: android, opencv, kivy

I am a newbie. I am trying to build an APK using Kivy Buildozer. I am using OpenCV library. Somehow Buildozer Android debug is always reporting errors.

Ubuntu 18.04.6LTS on a VMware Workstation
   Python 3.8.16

I want to know my how I should fix it correctly.

```
File "/home/chloe/ProgramFiles/anaconda3/envs/kapk/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 1357, in do_open
raise URLError(err)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 101] Network is unreachable>
Download failed: <urlopen error [Errno 101] Network is unreachable>; retrying in 1 second(s)...Download failed: <urlopen error [Errno 101] Network is unreachable>; retrying in 2 second(s)...Download failed: <urlopen error [Errno 101] Network is unreachable>; retrying in 4 second(s)...Download failed: <urlopen error [Errno 101] Network is unreachable>; retrying in 8 second(s)...# Command failed: ['/home/chloe/ProgramFiles/anaconda3/envs/kapk/bin/python', '-m', 'pythonforandroid.toolchain', 'create', '--dist_name=duapp', '--bootstrap=sdl2', '--requirements=kivy,python2,opencv-python', '--arch=arm64-v8a', '--arch=armeabi-v7a', '--copy-libs', '--color=always', '--storage-dir=/home/chloe/Desktop/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a', '--ndk-api=21', '--ignore-setup-py', '--debug']
# ENVIRONMENT:
#     CLUTTER_IM_MODULE = 'xim'
#     CONDA_SHLVL = '2'
#     CONDA_EXE = '/home/chloe/ProgramFiles/anaconda3/bin/conda'
#     LESSCLOSE = '/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s'
#     XDG_MENU_PREFIX = 'gnome-'
#     LANG = 'en_US.UTF-8'
#     MANAGERPID = '1525'
#     DISPLAY = ':0'
#     INVOCATION_ID = '4883bce309fb4d638b510e62273de382'
#     GNOME_SHELL_SESSION_MODE = 'ubuntu'
#     COLORTERM = 'truecolor'
#     USERNAME = 'chloe'
#     CONDA_PREFIX = '/home/chloe/ProgramFiles/anaconda3/envs/kapk'
#     XDG_VTNR = '2'
#     SSH_AUTH_SOCK = '/run/user/1000/keyring/ssh'
#     _CE_M = ''
#     XDG_SESSION_ID = '2'
#     USER = 'chloe'
#     CONDA_PREFIX_1 = '/home/chloe/ProgramFiles/anaconda3'
#     DESKTOP_SESSION = 'ubuntu'
#     QT4_IM_MODULE = 'xim'
#     TEXTDOMAINDIR = '/usr/share/locale/'
#     GNOME_TERMINAL_SCREEN = '/org/gnome/Terminal/screen/8715fa94_6677_4476_ad2f_58a9c7ffb74f'
#     PWD = '/home/chloe/Desktop/kivy'
#     HOME = '/home/chloe'
#     CONDA_PYTHON_EXE = '/home/chloe/ProgramFiles/anaconda3/bin/python'
#     JOURNAL_STREAM = '9:42315'
#     TEXTDOMAIN = 'im-config'
#     SSH_AGENT_PID = '1649'
#     QT_ACCESSIBILITY = '1'
#     XDG_SESSION_TYPE = 'x11'
#     XDG_DATA_DIRS = '/usr/share/ubuntu:/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/:/var/lib/snapd/desktop'
#     _CE_CONDA = ''
#     XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP = 'ubuntu'
#     DBUS_STARTER_ADDRESS = 'unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus,guid=eb419230a3da655b6a43ac71646185e0'
#     CONDA_PROMPT_MODIFIER = '(kapk) '
#     GTK_MODULES = 'gail:atk-bridge'
#     WINDOWPATH = '2'
#     TERM = 'xterm-256color'
#     SHELL = '/bin/bash'
#     VTE_VERSION = '5202'
#     QT_IM_MODULE = 'xim'
#     XMODIFIERS = '@im=ibus'
#     IM_CONFIG_PHASE = '2'
#     DBUS_STARTER_BUS_TYPE = 'session'
#     XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP = 'ubuntu:GNOME'
#     GPG_AGENT_INFO = '/run/user/1000/gnupg/S.gpg-agent:0:1'
#     GNOME_TERMINAL_SERVICE = ':1.66'
#     XDG_SEAT = 'seat0'
#     SHLVL = '1'
#     GDMSESSION = 'ubuntu'
#     GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID = 'this-is-deprecated'
#     LOGNAME = 'chloe'
#     DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS = 'unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus,guid=eb419230a3da655b6a43ac71646185e0'
#     XDG_RUNTIME_DIR = '/run/user/1000'
#     XAUTHORITY = '/run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority'
#     XDG_CONFIG_DIRS = '/etc/xdg/xdg-ubuntu:/etc/xdg'
#     PATH = '/home/chloe/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4/bin:/home/chloe/ProgramFiles/anaconda3/envs/kapk/bin:/home/chloe/ProgramFiles/anaconda3/condabin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin'
#     CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV = 'kapk'
#     SESSION_MANAGER = 'local/ubuntu:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/1554,unix/ubuntu:/tmp/.ICE-unix/1554'
#     LESSOPEN = '| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s'
#     GTK_IM_MODULE = 'ibus'
#     _ = '/home/chloe/ProgramFiles/anaconda3/envs/kapk/bin/buildozer'
#     PACKAGES_PATH = '/home/chloe/.buildozer/android/packages'
#     ANDROIDSDK = '/home/chloe/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk'
#     ANDROIDNDK = '/home/chloe/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r25b'
#     ANDROIDAPI = '31'
#     ANDROIDMINAPI = '21'
# 
# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# The error might be hidden in the log above this error
# Please read the full log, and search for it before
# raising an issue with buildozer itself.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
```

I wish I could package Python programs as APK.

Thanks in advance.